# Does not raise the exception

Tags: python, django, exception

My code is like below:

```
def getAllVehicles(self):
    try:
        vehobj = Vehicles.objects.all()            
    except VehicleDoesNotExists, e:
        logger.debug("Exception in getAllVehicles() is :::: %s ", e)
    return vehobj
```

And here is my test case:

```
def test_getAllVehicles(self):
    Vehicles.objects.all().delete()
    instance = Vehicles()
    self.assertRaises(VehicleDoesNotExists, instance.getAllVehicles)
```

Exception is never raised, but I require that:

```
 Vehicles.objects.all()
```

to raise an exception.
Code coverage is asking me to execute the except block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Vehicles.objects.all()` will give you an empty list... which is the correct behavior.  If you want to raise an exception, you can test for an empty list and `raise VehicleDoesNotExists(...)` yourself... but I don't understand why you'd want to.